# How to find all assignment expressions of a certain type

Tags: c, static-analysis

Say I have some struct definition like

```
struct sql_subtype {
    sql_type *type;
    unsigned int digits;
    unsigned int scale;
}
```

This struct sql_subtype is used all over the place in my codebase which is huge. Objects of this type are often members of other objects. So simple string matching is not good enough to find the assignment locations. Is there some nice trick or open source static-analysis tool that can give me the locations in the code base where any object of this type is being set to some value? Find all locations similar to

```
struct sql_subtype type1 = type2;
```

or

```
c1->t = c2->t; // where the t's are of the type of interest.
```

etc.

The general problem: given the class of expressions that involve a certain operator that returns a certain type, how can I find all statements that contain expressions of this class?

Comment: Maybe try [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coccinelle_(software)))?

Comment: Development environments like Eclipse can show all references to a selected identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Not a general solution, but there is a way to find the `struct` assignments with the C compiler alone. C allows you to declare **members** of struct as `const`, so you can add an extra member to the `struct` that is declared as `const` and only assignments will fail:

```
struct sql_subtype {
    unsigned int digits;
    unsigned int scale;
    const unsigned int poison_pill;
};

void function_call(struct sql_subtype foo) {
    struct sql_subtype initialized_from_copy = foo;
    initialized_from_copy.digits = 42;
    struct sql_subtype another = {0};
    another = foo;
}

// if the const member is the last one even initializer lists will work!
struct sql_subtype initialized = {1, 2};

int main(void) {
    function_call(initialized);
}
```

compile with GCC, and the only diagnostics you get are

```
constmemberhack.c: In function ‘function_call’:
constmemberhack.c:10:13: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘another’
     another = foo;
             ^
```